# Silverlight programmatic databind to Page Title Property not updating

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I'm using the Title property of a Page to set a textblock in the mainwindow.

Programmatic databinding is working for one time. But when i change the title property on a page the Browser title & tab are updated, but my textblock not.

In the NavigatedTo method in mainview:

```
Page page = ((Page)e.Content);

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Title");
binding.Source = page;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;

Header.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 1):

`Title` is not implemented as a dependency property hence bindings are not informed of changes made to it.

Ultimately you will need to co-operation of the code that changes the `Title` property.

Perhaps the simplest approach would be to create a `ChangeTitle` method on the Page and have that update both the `Title` property and the "Header" element.